# I fixed the header of my webpage to the top. Then why the content ate going under to the header?

Tags: html, css

I created a webpage. There is a header that will always stay at the top. For this I used absolute positioning. Now, when I scroll my page, the header works fine. It stays on the top all time. But some top part of content goes under the header. Then what I should do here??

Comment: please copy the code in snippet to help you

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't apply an `absolute` positioning in this case, because it'll tell the page to put it on top of everything independently of the other elements. You should use `position: fixed;` instead.

Here's a short example of a menu with this "sticky" header :

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
 padding:16px;
}
.sticky {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
.sticky + .content {
 padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/3/w3.css">
<div id="navbar" class="w3-bar w3-black" style="background:#000;z-index:1;">
 <a href="#" class="w3-button w3-bar-item w3-left w3-padding-16">MAIN MENU</a>
 <a href="#t" class="w3-button w3-bar-item w3-right w3-padding-16">CONTACT</a>
 <a href="#" class="w3-button w3-bar-item w3-right w3-padding-16">ABOUT</a>
 <a href="#" class="w3-button w3-bar-item w3-right w3-padding-16">CONTENT</a>
 <a href="#" class="w3-button w3-bar-item w3-right w3-padding-16">HOME</a>
</div>

<div class="content" class="w3-content w3-padding" style="max-width:1564px">

<img src="https://kittenrescue.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/KittenRescue_KittenCareHandbook.jpg" width="500" height="400" />
<br>
<img src="https://kittenrescue.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/KittenRescue_KittenCareHandbook.jpg" width="500" height="400" />
</div>
```

This will make the bar stay in the top without covering images or any content at the beginning, and it'll make the whole CSS stable, as its positioning is `block` by standard. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you should put your header position fixed and top :0; in css ie

```
#navbar{
         postion:fixed;
         top:0;
         height:100px;
}
```

and your content set it to a margin top of more than your navbar height

```
#content{
         margin-top:100px;
}
```